# Test data "disappearing" when using MSTest DynamicData

Tags: c#, mstest

I am using VS 2022 and have a c# library that targets framework 4.5 up to .net 6. I have a MS Test project for the library.  I use dynamic data heavily and recently noticed that not all of my test data was appearing in my test results. I have broken out the offending problem into as small as I can to prove out what I had been seeing.

If I put a breakpoint in HasExpectedItems2() and debug the test, I see it hit 3x and index is 0, 1, 2 respectively, as I would expect.  However, if I put a breakpoint in HasExpectedItems1() and debug the test, it only hits 2x, and items contains 3 items, and is null, respectively. I am not seeing items ever contain 0 items, which should be one of the data rows. If I comment out the 3rd List in DumbItems (which contains the 3 objects), HasExpectedItems1() still hits 2x, and items contains 0 items, and is null, respectively, as expected. So it appears by having a populated list, it somehow ignores the empty list. I've been trying to resolve this for days and am completely baffled on what is going on here.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
#if NET45_OR_GREATER
using System.Web.Mvc;
#elif NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
#endif

[TestClass]
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public class StaticTestingUnitTests
{
    protected static readonly IEnumerable<SelectListItem>[] DumbItems = new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>[]
    {
        null,
        new List<SelectListItem>(),
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "One", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Two", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Three", Value = "3" },
        },
    };

    protected static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDumbTest1()
    {
        foreach (object item in DumbItems)
        {
            yield return new object[] { item };
        }
    }

    protected static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDumbTest2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DumbItems.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return new object[] { i };
        }
    }

    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(GetDumbTest1), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
    public void HasExpectedItems1(IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(5, 5);
    }

    [DataTestMethod]
    [DynamicData(nameof(GetDumbTest2), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
    public void HasExpectedItems2(int index)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(5, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this should be reported as a bug to https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues Your tests are running fine with MSTest.TestAdapter/TestFramework version 2.2.3. If you upgrade to 2.2.5 you will see incorrect results you described (2.2.4 was deprecated, so I can only imaging a lot of things were broken there). Downgrade to 2.2.3 and test it yourself.

Comment: @Peska, Thank you very much.  This has been driving me nuts for days and I didn't think to move back to a previous version.  I reported as a bug so I'll see what happens with it.

Comment: I've just hit the exact same issue using version 2.2.10. Do you have some updates? Can you share the link to the bug report you made?

Answer (score 10):

This is happening due to an undocumented [breaking change in MsTest 2.2.4](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/compare/0b95a26282eae17f896d732381e5c77b9a603382...v2.2.4) which changes the default behavior for discovering ITestDataSource test cases (i.e. including `DynamicData`) to happen during Test Discovery instead of during Test Execution.

To restore the previous behavior, upgrade to MsTest 2.2.6 or newer, and add the following assembly attribute:

```cs
[assembly: TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution)]
```

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction, thanks. `TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringDetection)` (which is obviously the default) has some very strange side effects. For example, data sources which use `DateTime.Now` are evaluated and cached at detection time and hence contain unexpected values at execution time This should be documented somewhere and changed to opt-in model, as requested by many!