# Why does this DateTime.UtcNow input remain the same across test runs until the project is recompiled?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

Using the following setup in MsTest v2:

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData("TestInput")]
public void Test(DateTime datetime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(datetime);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestInput { 
    get => new List<object[]> { new object[] { DateTime.UtcNow } };
}
```

The output remains the same across test runs until the project is recompiled. For example:

```
/* Compiled test project */
Test output -> 11/16/2022 17:55:37
Test output -> 11/16/2022 17:55:37
Test output -> 11/16/2022 17:55:37
/* Recompile here */
Test output -> 11/16/2022 17:58:24
Test output -> 11/16/2022 17:58:24
Test output -> 11/16/2022 17:58:24
```

Can someone explain where the value of DateTime.UtcNow is being cached?

The behavior does indeed appear to be related to [Test data "disappearing" when using MSTest DynamicData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943832/test-data-disappearing-when-using-mstest-dynamicdata) and the time at which data sources are discovered. Closing then re-opening Visual Studio also causes the above output to update, and the discovery time can be modified by setting
`[assembly: TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution)]`.

Comment: What do you observe that made you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Best guess is that the test framework you're using calls `TestInput` once when you start running it and that's when the time is populated.

Comment: In most frameworks i know the methods creating input testdata for test are run once before all tests.

Comment: It isn't determined at compile time; the value can only be determined by running the code. That said, there is no requirement that the test framework actually call this property every time a test is run; it may well cache the values in ways you're not expecting. The bottom line is that you probably shouldn't be using `DynamicData` if you're expecting this value to be different for every test. (The term "dynamic" in the name is probably a bit of a misnomer; it's dynamic only in the sense that it's not a single constant value or file.)

Comment: Looks like worth to try this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71943832/test-data-disappearing-when-using-mstest-dynamicdata , which is adding `[assembly: TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution)]` attribute

Comment: Actually that is a good thing. How would you assert on the input data if it may change while testing? Using something like UtcNow in tests isn't wrong per se but it has a code smell. At least to me.